# Running a script when a table is updated in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ssms

I recently created a fairly lengthy SQL query script that takes the information of some base tables like forecast, bill of materials, part information and so on to automatically create a production schedule.

The script itself works well, but whenever something in those base tables changes the query script needs to be rerun (the script itself involves first dropping the tables created by the query, and then basically running the longer query of creating and dropping tables to get to the final schedule).

To make things easier on the front end user, my intention was to create a front end through access to allow the users to update the necessary base data.

My question is, is there a way to set something up either through Microsoft SSMS or Access (2016) that would run this script automatically whenever these tables were updated?

My initial search showed a lot of people talking about SQL Server Agent being able to automate queries, but I was not able to find anything regarding running a script when a table is updated, only scheduling things based on time frequency.

Ideally I think the easiest option would be if it were possible on the Access front end to allow the user to run this script by just pushing a button on a form, but I am open to whatever options would achieve the same goal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have table triggers that can detects data changes and run scripts as needed - Lookup SQL Triggers

Comment: Just be careful when using table triggers to run queries that can potentially take long as the user updating the table might experience performance issues. When using SQL Server you could consider using flags to kick off jobs.

Comment: A pattern you can use is a trigger that sets a flag in a table, and an agent job that runs every minute, checks if the flag is set, and runs if it is.